# Rings: working out the computational rule for a quotient polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

My question comes from Frederick M Goodman's text:

http://homepage.math.uiowa.edu/~goodman/algebrabook.dir/book.2.6.pdf

"Lets look at a particular example $K=\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)=x^2+1$. Then $\mathbb{R}[x]/f$ consists of cosets $a+bx+f$ represented by linear polynomials. Furthermore we have the computational rule:

$x^2+(f)=x^2+1-1+(f)=-1+(f)$

thus:

$(a+bx+(f))(a'+b'x+(f))=(aa'-bb')+(ab'+a'b)x+(f)$"

Im not understanding the second part of the last line. Any help?

p.s. Im trying to understand this so I can determine the computational rule for a the polynomial ring $\mathbb{R}/(f)$ where $(f)=x^3-1$. In this case the left cosets will be $a+bx+cx^2+(f)$ but how do I proceed?

EDIT: For the second part I have:

$(a+bx+cx^2+(f))(a'+b'x+c'x^2+(f))=aa'+(ab'+ba')x+(ac'+bb'+ca')x^2+(bc'+cb')x^3+cc'x^4+(a+bx+cx^2)(f)+(a'+b'x+c'x^2)(f)+(f)(f)$

Not sure how to proceed since I do not understand where the top line of the example comes from.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1482472/polynomial-quotient-ring-rule-of-computation#comment3019263_1482472)

Answer (score 0):

This is simply the result of multiplying out and simplifying:

$$
\begin{align*}
(a+bx+(f))(a'+b'x+(f))&=aa'+ab'x+a(f)+a'bx+bb'x^2+bx(f)+a'(f)+b'x(f)+(f)(f)\\
\end{align*}
$$
First: we know that all of the terms involving $(f)$ simplify down to $(f)$, so that we have
$$
(a+bx+(f))(a'+b'x+(f))=aa'+ab'x+a'bx+bb'x^2+(f).
$$
Now, by the above, we inver that $bb'x^2+(f)=bb'(-1)+(f)=-bb'+(f)$, so that
$$
(a+bx+(f))(a'+b'x+(f))=(aa'-bb')+(ab'+a'b)x+(f)
$$
as claimed.

As an added node: this should seem awfully familiar. The roots of $x^2+1=0$ are $x=\pm i$, the imaginary unit. And, you might recall that
$$
(a+bi)(a'+b'i)=aa'-bb'+(ab'+a'b)i.
$$
This is not a coincidence. :-)

Comment: hm I think that is my confusion: In the top line, why do we say that we have the computational rule "$x^2+(f)=..."$ Why not $x^2+1+(f)=...$?

Comment: The idea here is that your polynomial is degree 2... which means that everything survives the quotient will be degree 0 or 1.  (Thing polynomial division algorithm.)  When we initially multiplied it out, we saw that we got constant and linear terms just fine, and a whole bunch of stuff that collapsed in to $(f)$, which is fine... but we still had a leftover $x^2$ and coefficient.  So, we needed to understand how $x^2+(f)$ simplified.

Comment: Ok, So am I understanding this right if I say: $f(x)=x^3-1 implies x^3+(f)=x^3+1-1+(f)=1+(f)$ My polynomial when multiplied out has a x^4 term..do I drop this?

Comment: so with $x^3=1$ my expression becomes $aa'+bc'+cb'+(ab'+ba')x+(ac'+bb'+ca')x^2+cc'x^4+(a+bx+cx^2)(f)+(a'+b'x+c'x^2)(f)+(f)(f)$

Comment: There's still plenty of simplification to be done here.  For instance, if $x^3+(f)=1$, then $x(x^3+(f))=x^4+(f)$; so, $x^4+(f)=x+x(f)=x+(f)$.

Comment: Always think of quotients as identifying a bunch of elements as being equivalent to $0$, and studying the algebraic ramifications of that decision.